# Tracking "trailing" daily stats in Appengine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to present 7-day trailing stats from a certain Appengine Datastore field. If my model has an integer field "Foo", I want to be able to find the top N models by the increase in Foo over the last 7 days.

I think it is best to explain by example. Suppose we have two entities with a Foo field and we sample the value of Foo every day at midnight:

```
Day       01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13
User1.Foo  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  8  7  6  5
User2.Foo 50 55 50 45 50 55 50 45 50 55 50 45 50
```

I want to be able to construct (for each day) the 7-day delta:

```
Day       01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13
User1.FooDelta7d            6  6  6  4  2  0 -2
User2.FooDelta7d            0 -10 0  10 0 -10  0
```

And be able to query for users ORDER BY FooDelta7d.

I could solve this problem by keeping 7 extra entries on each user, like Foo1 Foo2 Foo3 ... Foo7 and take the day of year modulo 7 to decide which entry to write into at midnight:

```
Day       01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13
User1.Foo  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  8  7  6  5
User1.Foo1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  8  8  8  8  8  8
User1.Foo2    2  2  2  2  2  2  2  9  9  9  9  9
User1.Foo3       3  3  3  3  3  3  3  8  8  8  8
User1.Foo4          4  4  4  4  4  4  4  7  7  7
User1.Foo5             5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6
User1.Foo6                6  6  6  6  6  6  6  5
User1.Foo7                   7  7  7  7  7  7  7
```

So on (say) day 10, the delta is User1.Foo3 - User1.Foo4 = 8 - 4 = 4. This works but it seems really gross to me, especially since it means 8x storage per field I want to track.

Does anyone have a better idea? Thanks!

Comment: "keeping 7 extra entries" you mean "keeping 7 extra attributes"?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I meant keeping 7 extra db.IntegerProperty. But Peter points out below I could make it a single ListProperty.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to have a daily rolling 7-day-delta, you need to keep data for all past seven days. So it seems that what you are already doing is the right way.

To reduce "grossness" you might want to make Foo1..Foo7 a [list property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListPropertyhttp://).